# dynamic array with pointers to struct nodes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-data

I am having trouble with some code in C and i would really need your help . Well i have these 2 structs (they are asked to be like this so we cann't change them)

```
struct node{
    struct list_node **table;
    int table_size;
};

struct list_node{
    int num;
    struct list_node *ptr;
};
```

and as you can see in the first one we have an array , with pointers in the nodes of our list. in main , we create the needed memory space to begin like this

```
struct node *nodeT;
struct list_node *root, *curr, **temp;

root = (struct list_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));       // root node of list

nodeT = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));                // single node
nodeT->table = (struct list_node**)malloc(sizeof(struct list_node*)); 
nodeT->table_size = 0;
```

and then I creat the list

```
for(i=0 ; i<X ; i++){     // X is important for the errors and i'll explain why
  curr = (struct list_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
  curr -> num = (i+1);
  curr -> ptr = root;
  root = curr;
}
```

now , i run through the list and i expand the array in the first struct for everysingle list node i find ,  to enter a pointer to the proper node.

```
for(curr=root ; curr!=NULL ; curr=curr->ptr){               

  nodeT->table[nodeT->table_size] = curr;
  nodeT->table_size++;

  temp = (struct list_node**)realloc(nodeT->table , nodeT->table_size*sizeof(struct list_node *));
  if(temp!=NULL)
      nodeT->table = temp;
  else{
     printf("Memory error\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

i use this struct list_node **temp to keep safe nodeT and after checking , if everything is ok , i put temp in nodeT again , otherwise i stop the programm . In the end i print the contents of the list throught the pointers of array like this

```
for(i=0 ; i<nodeT->table_size ; i++)
   printf("-> %d ", nodeT->table[i]->num);
printf("\n");
```

and i exit the programm. the paradox in this , is that for X 1-4 everything works fine, but for 5+ there is a problem and i get a message

" ** glibc detected *** ./dynamix_table_realloc: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000819050 ***  "

and about 20 more lines , that dont realy help me. I hope you will , and thats why i posted this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not allocate enough memory at here:

```
temp = (struct list_node**)realloc(nodeT->table , nodeT->table_size*sizeof(struct list_node *));
```

It should be:

```
temp = (struct list_node**)realloc(nodeT->table , (nodeT->table_size+1)*sizeof(struct list_node *));
```

You use `realloc()` to add space for the next element, but after `nodeT->table_size++`, the value of `nodeT->table->size` is the *index* of next element, because the C array index is zero-based, so the number of elements should be `nodeT->table_size + 1`.

This is a typical [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).